# Symfony2 + Bootstrap3: customization of "block form_label" causes flipped form

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, symfony-forms

I wanted to place some icons with links on the right part of the labels. It's almost 100% solved (read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195932/placing-stuff-between-a-symfony-form-label-and-the-widget-using-bootstrap) for the full story)

In summary I overrode the block `{%- block form_label -%}` in another template like follows (I just added the "ADDED PART" below):

```
{% extends "bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig"%}

{%- block form_label -%}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) -%}
        {% if not compound -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                    '%name%': name,
                    '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>{{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
        // START OF ADDED PART
        {% if 'history' in label_attr.class %}
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{historyUrl}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        {% endif %}
        {% if 'help' in label_attr.class %}
            <a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{helpUrl}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        {% endif %}
        // END OF ADDED PART
        </label>
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label -%}
```

Everything works but my form is flipped (labels on the right).

This is what I get:

[image]

I tried some combinations of adding `parent` here and there, but it causes a duplication of labels.

I suspect that's because I'm overriding a portion of the `form_div_layout.html.twig` which gets later extended by the `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig` and I extend the latter.

Any hint on how to solve it?

I'm using the form template assigning it at a global level in the config.yml

```
# Twig Configuration

twig:
    ...
    form_themes: ['Form/form_errors.html.twig']
    form:
        resources: ['Form/mylayout.html.twig']
```

**EDIT**

Partially solved but I don't like the solution, looking forward to a more elegant one. What I did was.

1) Creating a template which uses `form_div_layout.html.twig` adding my label customization.

2) Copy pasting the `bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig` changing the first line to make it use 1)

3) Copy pasting the `bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig` changing the first line to make it extend 2)

4) Finally use 3) in as form theme

A bit of an overkill...other solutions more than welcome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you lost few classes for bootstrap and this is why your markup is broken.
Try this one form_label block^

```
{% block form_label -%}
{% spaceless %}
    {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' control-label ' ~ block('form_label_class'))|trim}) %}
    {% if label is not sameas(false) -%}
        {% if not compound -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if required -%}
            {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
        {%- endif %}
        {% if label is empty -%}
            {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
                {% set label = label_format|replace({
                '%name%': name,
                '%id%': id,
                }) %}
            {%- else -%}
                {% set label = name|humanize %}
            {%- endif -%}
        {%- endif -%}
        <label{% for attrname, attrvalue in label_attr %} {{ attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"{% endfor %}>
            {{ label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}
            // START OF ADDED PART
            {% if 'history' in label_attr.class %}
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{historyUrl}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
            {% if 'help' in label_attr.class %}
                <a data-toggle="modal" href="#{{helpUrl}}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
            {% endif %}
            // END OF ADDED PART
        </label>
    {%- endif -%}
{% endspaceless %}
{%- endblock form_label %}
```

I've just added first line for set lost classes that needed for bootstrap:

```
{% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({class: (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' control-label ' ~ block('form_label_class'))|trim}) %}
```